# how to get value by checking the range between another tables two column in DB2

Tags: sql, db2

i have a column with id and date_id in source, i want to fetch the date_skey of that date_id from other table if the date_id exists in the range of other tables start_date and end_date.

```
TABLE 1 
    id | date_id
    01 | 20201009
    02 | 20161009
    
    TABLE 2
    id | date_skey | start_date       | end_date
    1  |    254    | 2019-01-01 00:00 | 9999-12-31 00:00
    2  |    345    | 2017-01-01 00:00 | 2017-06-30 00:00

    OUTPUT
    id | date_id  | date_skey 
    01 | 20201009 | 254
```

i am using DB2 and new to it, my attempt was this

```
select tab1.id,tab1.date_id,tab2.date_skey
from tab.1
  where exists(
        select 1 from tab.2 where tab1.id = tab2.id and tab1.date_id
    between replace(left(tab2.start_date,10),'-','') and replace(left(tab2.end_date,10),'-',''));
```

also tried this

```
select tab1.id,tab1.date_id
from tab.1
where exists(
        select 1 from tab.2 where tab1.id = tab2.id and tab1.date_id
    between replace(left(tab2.start_date,10),'-','') and replace(left(tab2.end_date,10),'-',''));
```

but its giving me error.
what i am doing wrong?
thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the column types of `date_id`, `start_date`, and `end_date`?

Comment: thanks for your time, date_id - decimal(10), start and end date - timesatmp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "easy" way out here is to just maintain the `date_id` as a bona fide date or timestamp column.  Then, you would only need a simple inner join with a range comparison.  We can still use that approach given your current table design, but we need some casting on the `date_id` numeric column, to convert it to a formal date.

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.date_id, t2.date_skey
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON TO_DATE(CAST(t1.date_id AS VARCHAR(8)), 'YYYYMMDD')
       BETWEEN t2.start_date AND t2.end_date;
```